# Slow SharePoint 2016 performance that gets fixed with a server restart

Tags: sharepoint-server, performance

We have a SharePoint 2016 on prem server that sometimes slows down in performance and usually restarting the server fixes it.  I realise there might be a list of possible reasons, but from this forum's users' experience, what could be the most obvious reasons for this?  (there were no latest software update on the server, so it can't be the reason)

Comment: It can be dozens of reasons. Does it degrade each day? Do you have any custom solutions deployed?

Comment: There are one custom solution that uploads documents from a ERP solution.  Only creating folders and uploading a file.  It does not degrade every day, it happens once in 2 weeks.